# SQL Identify related rows (Hierarchal)

Tags: sql

I need to identify rows that are related to each other using two fields, to some extent it is a hierarchy, but cant get CTE to work.

This is a simplified table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LinkedRows](
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [COL1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [COL2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [LINK] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Here's some data:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.LinkedRows (ID, COL1, COL2) VALUES (1, 'A','B')
INSERT INTO dbo.LinkedRows (ID, COL1, COL2) VALUES (2, 'C','B')
INSERT INTO dbo.LinkedRows (ID, COL1, COL2) VALUES (3, 'A','D')
INSERT INTO dbo.LinkedRows (ID, COL1, COL2) VALUES (4, 'D','A')
INSERT INTO dbo.LinkedRows (ID, COL1, COL2) VALUES (5, 'B','A')
INSERT INTO dbo.LinkedRows (ID, COL1, COL2) VALUES (6, 'E','C')
INSERT INTO dbo.LinkedRows (ID, COL1, COL2) VALUES (7, 'B','C')
INSERT INTO dbo.LinkedRows (ID, COL1, COL2) VALUES (8, 'C','E')
INSERT INTO dbo.LinkedRows (ID, COL1, COL2) VALUES (9, 'F','G')
INSERT INTO dbo.LinkedRows (ID, COL1, COL2) VALUES (10, 'G','H')
```

This is what I'm trying to determine:

```
ID      COL1    COL2    linked
1       A       B       1
2       C       B       1
3       A       D       1
4       D       A       1
5       B       A       1
6       E       C       1
7       B       C       1
8       C       E       1
9       F       G       2
10      G       H       2
```

Rows 1 and 2 both have B in COL2, so A, B and C are all related to each other and have been given the same linked number (ID). 
In rows 3 and 4 we have A,D and D,A since there is a combination of B,A in row 5, D can be linked to B through A, so now we can link A, B, C, D together.
In row 6 and 8 we have E,C and C,E so we can now link A, B, C, D, E together.
Row 7 is just the opposite of row 2.
In row 9 we have F,G since we cant make a link from either of these to A,B,C,D,E another linked group is created.
In row 10 we have G,H which can be linked to linked group 2 through G ie, F,G,H are related.

Any help or advice greatly appreciated.

Regards
CM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this can be done recursively with CTE in a nice way.

But since you already have the LINK field in your table, you can use SQL code to fill out this field. You'll have to run the code every time the data has been changed:

```sql
-- Reset LINK
UPDATE LinkedRows SET LINK = NULL;

-- Declare variables
DECLARE @LinkCounter int;
DECLARE @myID int;
DECLARE @myCOL1 nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @myCOL2 nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @myLINK1 int;
DECLARE @myLINK2 int;
-- Init group counter
SET @LinkCounter = 0;

DECLARE RowCursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT ID, COL1, COL2 FROM LinkedRows ORDER BY ID;

OPEN RowCursor;

-- Run through all records
FETCH NEXT FROM RowCursor INTO @myID, @myCOL1, @myCOL2;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 -- More records
    BEGIN
        DECLARE LinkCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT(LINK) FROM LinkedRows WHERE (COL1 = @myCOL1 OR COL1 = @myCOL2 OR COL2 = @myCOL1 OR COL2 = @myCOL2) AND NOT LINK IS NULL;
        OPEN LinkCursor;
        FETCH NEXT FROM LinkCursor INTO @myLINK1;
        IF @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 -- At least one record
            BEGIN
                FETCH NEXT FROM LinkCursor INTO @myLINK2;
                IF @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 -- Two records present - Link two groups
                    BEGIN
                        -- SELECT 'Link', @myLINK1, @myLINK2; -- Debug
                        -- Join the groups - use the first LINK id
                        UPDATE LinkedRows SET LINK = @myLINK1 WHERE LINK = @myLINK2;
                        -- Add the new record to the group
                        UPDATE LinkedRows SET LINK = @myLINK1 WHERE ID = @myID;
                    END;
                ELSE -- Only one group - assign new record to existing group
                    BEGIN
                        -- SELECT 'Assign', @myLINK1; -- Debug
                        UPDATE LinkedRows SET LINK = @myLINK1 WHERE ID = @myID;
                    END;
            END;
        ELSE -- New group
            BEGIN
                SET @LinkCounter = @LinkCounter + 1;
                -- SELECT 'New', @LinkCounter;
                UPDATE LinkedRows SET LINK = @LinkCounter WHERE ID = @myID;
            END;
        CLOSE LinkCursor
        DEALLOCATE LinkCursor
        -- Get next record
        FETCH NEXT FROM RowCursor INTO  @myID, @myCOL1, @myCOL2;
    END;
CLOSE RowCursor;
DEALLOCATE RowCursor;
```

Now the LINK field will contain the linked group.

**EDITED** Updated the code to handle the case where two groups would be joined, by a linking record.

Comment: Many thanks your code works great, my real world data could contain quite a few rows so I stayed away from using cursors, would you say that cursors are unavoidable in this scenario? Thanks again very much appreciated.

Comment: I think it will be difficult to avoid some kind of iteration, either with a cursor in T-SQL or by using some external code to run through the data.
For a recursive CTE to work you will need a well defined termination condition (anchor member), and I can't see how to define it in this case.

Comment: My first answer was flawed. It did not handle the case where two groups would be joined by a later record. Ex: If there was a record: (ID, COL1, COL2) VALUES (11, 'C','H') the two previous groups should be joined to one. Updated the code to handle this.